# Is there a (simplified) way to add config/host builder to service collection in .net core console?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, serilog

I have a code that's supposed to register serilog and http client but one is with config builder and the other is with service collection. Looking for a way to simplify the code so I'm just using one of the classes to register both.

```
static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
BuildConfig(builder);
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build()).Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
Log.Logger.Information("Application started");
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
    //.ConfigureServices((context, services) => 
    //{ 
        
    //}).UseSerilog().Build();

var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient()    
    .BuildServiceProvider(); //AddLogging(builder => { builder.AddSerilog(); });

var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Answer (score 2):

An `IHost` already includes an `IServiceProvider`, you don't need to manually create that.

Keep in mind that you usually shouldn't access factories manually or request services without a scope. The example below includes the recommended way to get an instance of `HttpClient`.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(hostConfig =>
    {
        hostConfig.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        hostConfig.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        hostConfig.AddEnvironmentVariables($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true);
        hostConfig.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddSerilog();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        //Also add other services you want
    })
    .Build();

//Bad practice
var httpClientFactory = host.Services.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client1 = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

//Good Practice
using(IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var client2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<HttpClient>();
}
```

Comment: Serilog is null when I run it and `AddEnvironmentVariables` only takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using host instead of service collection:

```
IConfiguration builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }).UseSerilog().Build();
```